# Batch files to delete all folders starting with a specific name

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to write a batch file that deletes all the folders starting with a specific name eg: Smart. The following command only removes the sub folders but not the folder itself. Also it does not filter other folders starting with the name smart.

```
@RD /S /Q "C:\Users\Documents\Smart"
```

Comment: `for /d /r %%i in (smart*) do echo rd "%%~fi" /S /Q` Only remove `echo` from the line once the desired results were printed to screen, just a safety measure.

Comment: Thank you !! Removed echo and I am getting the desired results.